# Reference a variable that is inside a "with open" block inside a function

Tags: python, function, txt

```
def write_lor():
    with open("data.txt", 'r+') as filehandle:
        filecontents = filehandle.readlines()
        filehandle.seek(0)
        new = (int(filecontents[0])+1)
        filehandle.write(str(new))
        filehandle.truncate()
```

This is a basic counter sort of system that saves to a txt. Is there anyway to reference the variable `new` later down the line? For example my usage is:

```
button1 = Button(frame, text=("Left On Read:\n", **VARIABLE**), fg="black", bg="white", height = 5, width = 20, command=write_lor)
```

with the **variable** needing to be the variable `new` referenced in the function above.

Comment: You'll have to make it a global variable; there's no way to access the local variable `new` after `write_lor` returns.

Comment: You could update the text inside the button from inside your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def write_lor():
    with open("data.txt", 'r+') as filehandle:
        filecontents = filehandle.readlines()
        filehandle.seek(0)
        global lor
        lor = (int(filecontents[0])+1)
        filehandle.write(str(lor)+ "\n")
```

Comment: Please add documentation explaining why this solution works, what it targets, and the problem it tries to address.

Comment: Please be more elaborate, provide an [explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) for your answer.